# Table too wide for page

Tags: longtable, hyphenation

I am trying to fit a rather large table to my page. It is to wide for the page. I tried something like

```
\begin{longtable}{| p{0.14\textwidth} | p{0.14\textwidth} | 
p{0.14\textwidth} | p{0.14\textwidth} | p{0.14\textwidth} | 
p{0.14\textwidth} | p{0.14\textwidth} |}
```

because I have seven columns.

One of the problems I now have is that, as I'm using `scrartcl`, the annotation space is included into `\textwidth` too, but of course I want to stay inside the normal limits.

Also, I am already using footnotesize, but it does not separate words --> if they are too long, they are partially written in the next column.

I now need a method, that fits the table into the "normal" page width (as shown by `showframe`) and also adds a linebreak or separates words, in order to avoid writing into the next column.

I didn't post a minimal example, because I'm open to every possible solution, (but it should use something like longtable and, if possible, adjust the column size in relation to the `\textwidth`).
(sorry if this looks a bit messy)

```
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{center}
  \begin{longtable}{| p{0.14\textwidth} | p{0.14\textwidth} |
  p{0.14\textwidth} | p{0.14\textwidth} | p{0.14\textwidth} | 
  p{0.14\textwidth} | p{0.14\textwidth} |}
    \hline 
  \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Kurzbezeichnung} & \textbf{Frage} & \textbf{type} & \textbf{value label} & \textbf{Range} & \textbf{missing value}\\
  \hline
  \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
  ffhrwoggbgbgfieh & fefgogergeroigregb & fhoergregre & fhoerghergie & herogheggire & hgieghrgri & ngjreoigehrero\\
  \hline
  \caption{Alle Variablen von der Dokumentation aus dem Codebuch.}
  \label{tab:VarDoku}
  \end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{footnotesize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you add the complete code. Thus we can help you.

Comment: There are 2 ways of formatting code -- for long blocks indenting by 4 spaces (or highlight and press the `{}` button on the full website) looks better than backticks.  An image would help, as there are a few ideas, some but not all of which would work in any particular situation.  If you're on the desktop version of the website, the "related" links to the right might be helpful

Comment: You're writing in German by the look of things.  I don;t know how hyphenation patterns are handled in compound words in German, but I would guess that for long uncommon compounds you need to specify that patterns at the start of your document for example `\hyphenation{electro-reflect-ance thermo-reflect-ance electro-lumin-escence}`

Comment: @ChriSH: thank you for editing, it is not only this table, I have several tables in my document, all of them a bit different, so it should be an example that works for all kinds of large tables, if possible.

Comment: Isn't there a command that automatizes german hyphenation? As it is a  large document, I can't possibly specify all of it.

Comment: Ok, for german hyphenation, you just have to `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. That still doesn't solve the problem that it writes into the next column, though.

Comment: You don't need to specify every place you want a hyphen.  You need to specify hyphenation patterns for words that aren't in the hyphenation dictionary, and realistically only long words.  It depends how thorough the built-in hyphenation patterns are.   But if that is the underlying issue, I would hang on for input from one of the many knowledgeable German-writing members.  This is likely to be a common problem and there is likely be an easier route than manually specifying a lot of words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way “Kurzbezeichnung” can be accommodated in such a narrow width, so I abbreviated it into ”KB”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,calc,array}

\newlength\alicewidth

\begin{document}

\begingroup\footnotesize
\setlength{\alicewidth}{\textwidth/7-2\tabcolsep-8\arrayrulewidth/7}
\begin{longtable}{|*{7}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\alicewidth}|}}
\hline
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{KB} & \textbf{Frage} &
  \textbf{type} & \textbf{value label} & \textbf{Range} & \textbf{missing value}\\
\hline
\endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page

ffhrwo ggbgbg fieh & fefgo gerge roigr egb & fhoerg regre & fhoerg hergie &
 herogh eggire & hgieg hrgri & ngjreoi gehrero\\

\hline
\caption{Alle Variablen von der Dokumentation aus dem Codebuch.\label{tab:VarDoku}}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that did nearly all I wanted, I still have problems with some words that are to long for the column, do I have to specify these with `\hyphenation` then?

Comment: @LizzAlice - You could provide the instruction `\hyphenation{kurz-be-zeich-nung}` in the preamble *and* write the cell as `\hspace{0pt}\textbf{Kurzbezeichnung}`. (The `\hspace{0pt}` directive serves to enable hyphenation of the subsequent word.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `ltablex` package, which combines the functionalities of `longtable` and `tabularx`,  and `makecell` to have a common formatting of all column heads. Also, table captions usually are placed *above* table, especially in the case of multipage tables, for the reader's ease:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, ltablex, makecell}%
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize, labelfont=sc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\usepackage{showframe} %
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\footnotesize\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\
\keepXColumns
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{7}{ X|}}
  \caption{Alle Variablen von der Dokumentation aus dem Codebuch.}\medskip
  \label{tab:VarDoku}\\
  \hline \thead{Variable} & \thead{Kurzbe- & & & & & \\zeichnung} & \thead{Frage} & \thead{Type} & \thead{Value\\ label} & \thead{Range} & \thead{Missing\\ value}\\
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \hline
  \thead{Variable} & \thead{Kurzbe- & & & & & \\zeichnung} & \thead{Frage} & \thead{type} & \thead{value\\ label} & \thead{Range} & \thead{missing\\ value}\\
  \hline
  \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
  ffhrwogg bgbgfieh & fefgogerge roigregb & fhoergregre & fhoerghergie & herogheggire & hgieghrgri & ngjreoigeh rero \\

  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]